# Jquery Expand Collapse not working in AJAX Success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm stuck with this problem. I have an `AJAX in jQuery` and inside of `success` I make an HTML  tag and append this to the HTML outside of jQuery functionality. My problem is that the HTML tag that I will append to will expand and collapse. I don't know what is the problem why it does not expand collapse when I apply the class name inside that html tag.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('ul.group').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).next().is(':visible')) {
            $(event.target).next().find('ul').slideUp(250, function() {
                $(event.target).next().slideUp(250);
            });
        } else {
            $(event.target).parent().siblings().find("ul").slideUp(250);
            $(event.target).next().slideDown(250);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my css:

```
.group ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #cccccc;
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="stage">

</div>
```

And here is my jQuery AJAX:

```
$( "#search_batch_structure" ).click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo base_url()?>project/search_project_structure_stage',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
                project_id: $('#project_id').val()
              },
        success : function(stages)
                {
                    var stages = $.parseJSON(stages);
                    for (var i = 0; i < stages.length; i++)
                    {
                        stageID = stages[i].ID;
                        stagename = stages[i].StageName;
                        stageorder = stages[i].ordStage;

                        var html_stage = "<ul id='"+stageID+"' class='group'><li class='plusimageapply'><a onclick='return false;'>" + stagename + "&nbsp;" + stageorder + "</a>";
                        $('#stage').append(html_stage);

                        $.ajax({
                        url : '<?php echo base_url()?>project/search_project_structure_batch',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { 
                                'stage_id': stageID,
                              },
                        success : function(batch)
                                {
                                    var batch = $.parseJSON(batch);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < batch.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        batchID = batch[i].BatchID;
                                        batchname = batch[i].BatchName;
                                        batchorder= batch[i].ordBatch;
                                        stageid = batch[i].StageID;

                                        var html_batch = "<ul id='"+batchID+"' class='group'><li class='plusimageapply'><a onclick='return false;'>" + batchname + "&nbsp;" + batchorder + "</a>";
                                        $('#'+stageid).append(html_batch);

                                        $.ajax({
                                        url : '<?php echo base_url()?>project/search_project_structure_activity',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: { 
                                                'batch_id': batchID,
                                              },
                                        success : function(activity)
                                                {
                                                    var activity = $.parseJSON(activity);
                                                    for (var i = 0; i < activity.length; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        activityID = activity[i].ActivityID;
                                                        activityname = activity[i].ActivityName;
                                                        activityorder = activity[i].ordActivity;
                                                        batchid = activity[i].BatchID;
                                                        var html_batch = "<ul><li class='selectedimage'>" + activityname + "&nbsp;" + activityorder + "</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>";
                                                        $('#'+batchid).append(html_batch);
                                                    }


                                                }
                                        });
                                    }


                                }
                        });
                    }
                }
        });
    });
```

I'm thinking if it didn't work because it only append?
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If your `ul.group` elements are being added by the success function of the AJAX call, you can't bind a delegated event handler to them when the page loads. You'll instead need to bind the event handler to the element that *does* exist (i.e. `#stage`):

```
$('#stage').delegate('ul.group a', 'click', function(e) {
    // your logic here
});
```

On a related note, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, you should use the delegated event form of `.on()` instead:

```
$('#stage').on('click', 'ul.group a', function(e) {
    // code
});
```

Comment: it's not mandatory to use `on`. delegate is not deprecated as far as i know, it still works with latest version of query. only `live()` is deprecated..

Comment: @TJ `.on()` is the recommended way now a days.

Comment: i know. then you should say "it's recommended to use" or so. Otherwise it'll sound like it does not exist anymore and you can't use that syntax past 1.7...

Comment: @TJ As far as I'm concerned what I've written is exactly the same as what you think I should have written. I used the word "should" - it's a suggestion that that's the preferable method to be using - not the phrase "have to" which would imply that they absolutely can't use `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you're delegating the event handler to another element which is also dynamically generated. You need to bind the handler to an element that's not added dynamically.

instead of

```
$('ul.group').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {

})
```

try

```
$(document).delegate('ul.group a', 'click', function(event) { //or any other element that stays in page

});
```

Comment: @user987654321 try removing the return false from `<a onclick='return false;'>"`